# Can i customize issuer url in Keycloak / Red hat SSO?

Tags: spring-boot, docker, single-sign-on, keycloak, redhat

I'm using local Red Hat Single Sign-On (SSO) to secure a Dockerized Spring Boot application. The application's authentication relies on JWTs generated by the Red Hat SSO instance. However, I'm encountering an issue where the issuer ("iss") is not being recognized.

Im using `host.docker.internal` to be able to communicate with the local RH-SSO server in the containerized spring app

in application.properies:

```
spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.issuer-uri= http://host.docker.internal:8888/auth/realms/MyRealm
spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.jwk-set-uri= http://host.docker.internal:8888/auth/realms/MyRealm/protocol/openid-connect/certs
```

Snippet of what happens

```
2023-08-31 01:36:25 2023-08-30 23:36:25.648 [http-nio-8080-exec-5] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - Securing POST /log/rest-log
2023-08-31 01:36:25 2023-08-30 23:36:25.660 [http-nio-8080-exec-5] DEBUG o.s.web.client.RestTemplate - HTTP GET http://host.docker.internal:8888/auth/realms/MyRealm/protocol/openid-connect/certs
2023-08-31 01:36:25 2023-08-30 23:36:25.661 [http-nio-8080-exec-5] DEBUG o.s.web.client.RestTemplate - Accept=[text/plain, application/json, application/*+json, */*]
2023-08-31 01:36:25 2023-08-30 23:36:25.859 [http-nio-8080-exec-5] DEBUG o.s.web.client.RestTemplate - Response 200 OK
2023-08-31 01:36:25 2023-08-30 23:36:25.860 [http-nio-8080-exec-5] DEBUG o.s.web.client.RestTemplate - Reading to [java.lang.String] as "application/json"
2023-08-31 01:36:28 2023-08-30 23:36:28.559 [http-nio-8080-exec-5] DEBUG o.s.s.oauth2.jwt.JwtClaimValidator - The iss claim is not valid
2023-08-31 01:36:28 2023-08-30 23:36:28.559 [http-nio-8080-exec-5] DEBUG o.s.s.o.s.r.a.JwtAuthenticationProvider - Failed to authenticate since the JWT was invalid
```

The issue apparently is that when i decode the JWT token the iss field is `"iss": "http://localhost:8888/auth/realms/MyRealm"` so i think it tries to match localhost to host.docker.internal